# best way to encode javascript with php for ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The following PHP function outputs JS:

```
function dothething( $data ){
    $res = "
        <div id=\"blah\">
            Here's some stuff, ". $data['name'] ."
        </div>";
    echo "$('#container').html('". $res ."');";
}
```

This function is called via jQuery's `$.ajax()`, using `dataType: 'script'` ... so whatever is `echo`ed runs like a JS function. There's more to it of course, but my question has to do with encoding. The ajax will fail when `$res` contains newlines or apostrophes. So adding this above the `echo` seems to be working for now:

```
$res = str_replace("\n", "\\n", addslashes($res));
```

Is this the best way to format the PHP variable `$res` to yield valid javascript for ajax?

Is there anything else I should add in there?

Comment: Yes, you should use `json_encode()` if you want to be certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case I would use `json_encode()` over anything else:

```
echo "$('#container').html(" . json_encode($res) . ");";
```

When applied to a string value, it will automatically encapsulate it with double quotes and escape anything inside that would otherwise cause a parse error.

Comment: Right now \r and \n are escaped?

Comment: @TomSarduy Why would that be a problem?

Comment: fantastic! this handles every bizarre exception and glitch. thank you :)

Comment: Let me try to explain: What if `$data` is `var d = JSON.parse('["a\\nb"]'); alert(d);`. Will alert: `a b` (without the new line), do I need to parse json to get the `b` on a new line or maybe double encode?

Comment: @TomSarduy `json_encode()` doesn't produce something that can be parsed with `JSON.parse()`, it produces valid JavaScript data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(count($result)>0) {
    $status = 0;
} else {
    $status = 1;
}   

$json['status'] = $status;
$json['result'] = $output;
print(json_encode($json));
```